# pgadmin3: FATAL: Ident authentification failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pgadmin

I'm trying to register new server in pgadmin3 with following settings:

```
Name: postgres
Host: localhost
Username: postgres
Password: <password which works for psql>
Service: empty or postgres
```

But it shows error:

```
FATAL: Ident authentification failed for user "postgres"
```

I've restarted postgresql service, but to no avail.

Contents of /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident
```

EDIT: Tools -> Server Configuration -> pg_hba.conf is greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like PgAdmin-III is probably connecting over IPv6 by default, so it's using the `ident` line that matches the IPv6 address for localhost, `::1/128`.

If you want to use password authentication, you probably want:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

I'm not sure why you have the unix domain socket line set to `trust`, but that's probably OK if it's just a development machine, so leave it unchanged. It's really much safer to have it as `ident` (if you want the unix user to have to be the same as the Pg user) or `md5` (for password auth on local unix sockets) though.

You'll need to edit `pg_hba.conf` directly in a text editor if PgAdmin-III doesn't have permissions to edit it. You could run PgAdmin-III as user `postgres` via `sudo`, but it's way safer (and probably easier) to just use `nano` or a similar command-line text editor to modify `pg_hba.conf`.

The password works for `psql` because `psql` will, unless told otherwise, connect over a unix domain socket, and you have that set to `trust`. You'll probably find you could give *any* password to `psql` and it'll still work, because it's never being asked to actually give the password, it's just being automatically trusted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this type of error is seen by every newbie user to pgadmin.
I have found this solution and it worked for me.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

This will ask for your system password and then you will get the postgres prompt.

and then in psql type below command to change the password.

```
\password
```

now enter the new password and re-enter it.

Answer (score 0):

PostGreSQL Account Debugging Steps (Linux Specific):

1. Make sure you actually have it installed (not just the client, the server too).
2. Make sure it is running.
3. Make sure you know *where* this is - usually in **/var/lib/pgsql/data** - however this could be anywhere - /var/lib/pgsql/unrelated-instance. Check your **postgres process** to see which directory (-D argument) this is.
4. Modify the **pg_hba.conf** file in the directory from the last step. I have no idea why this step isn't in the postgres documentation.
5. The specific configuration has been covered in e.g. Jay and Craig Ringer's answer. Make sure to configure **both** IPV4 and IPV6.
6. **Restart the server.**
7. Test that your configuration worked. Repeat 5-7 until you can login successfully.
8. **Important** Don't stop! Now you should configure a more secure password option - postgres may be fine for doing quick local setup, but you want to be using a more secure, configurable authentication mechanism, like LDAP, Kerberos, or GSSAPI. Additionally, you want to make sure you have SSL turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Change the password of default user

> ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';